# Perl Global Symbol requires explicit package name error

Tags: perl

Why does this Perl code give me an error?

```
my $next_maximum = 0;
my $corresponding_key;
my $count_to_ten = 0;
my %top10words; #the new hash
while (count_to_ten < 10) {
  $next_maximum = 0;
  $corresponding_key = "";
  while (my ($key, $value) = each(%words)) {
    if ($next_maximum<$value) {
      $next_maximum = $value;
      $corresponding_key = $key;
    }
  }
  delete $words{$corresponding_key}; #remove the maximum from the original word list
  $top10words($corresponding_key) = $next_maximum;
  $count_to_ten++;
}
```

The line `$top10words($corresponding_key) = $next_maximum;` gives an error which says `Global symbol "$top10words" requires explicit package name at lab2.pl`.  I don't understand what this means but I think it is due to variable scope.  I feel like I have declared my variables within the proper scope, so I am stuck.

Comment: Instead of going through all the keys like this, why not just use Perl to sort the hash by value? See my response to your other question.

Comment: Because I would have had to design my own sorting algorithm!  I guess I did do that here, in a sense, but it was much simpler and suited exactly what I needed in this case.  I wasn't dealing with an extreme amount of information, so performance hits weren't really an issue in the first place, and this ended up working just fine (after fixing it, of course).

Comment: sorting hashes by value is a very common idiom in Perl. `sort { $hash{$a} cmp $hash{$b} } keys %hash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$top10words($corresponding_key)
```

should be

```
$top10words{$corresponding_key}
```

The error is because you are (unintentionally) using the undeclared scalar `$top10words`, not the hash `%top10words`.

Comment: Oh my goodness, thank you so much.  Probably would have stared at that for quite some more time, but i clearly just needed a second set of eyes.